# Assign multiple responsibilities to a user in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms, oracle-apps, oracle-ebs

I am aiming to do something as follows:

Say there are responsibilities in oracle 11 as,

- resp 1
- resp 2
- resp 3
- resp 4 ...

I wish to assign, say,

- resp 1, resp 3, .. to 1K users, and
- resp 2, resp 4,.. to different 1K users.

**Q1]** Is it possible to group them like

- resp grp 1 => resp 1, resp 3, ...
- resp grp 2 => resp 2, resp 4, ...

**Q2]** What's best way to assign to users?

I tried to find on google and SO, but did not found any post about responsibility grouping (don't know if it's possible).

Consider I have not much knowledge of subject.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What are "responsibilities"? Is this, by any chance, an Oracle Apps. / E-Business Suite question?

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: You can definitely assign multiple responsibilities to a user; however, there is no way to do this in mass through the front end.  You will need to research on `fndload` which is a scripted way to upload/download objects from EBS.  You can leverage it with users and responsibilities.

Comment: I believe the structure is user->role->responsibility-function. So then you would create a new role and assign your responsibilities. Then assign that role to your user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below API to assign responsibilities to users. You can create a table with the required details and create a program/script to assign responsibilities to users.

```
-- ----------------------------------------------------------
-- Add Responsibility to Oracle FND User
-- -----------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE
    l_user_name              VARCHAR2 (100) := 'BALA';
    l_resp_appl_short_name   VARCHAR2 (100) := 'XDO';
    l_responsibility_key     VARCHAR2 (100) := 'XDO_ADMINISTRATION';
    l_security_group_key     VARCHAR2 (100) := 'STANDARD';
    l_resp_start_date        DATE := TO_DATE ('22-05-2019');
    l_resp_end_date          DATE := NULL;
BEGIN
    fnd_user_pkg.addresp (
        username         => l_user_name
        , resp_app         => l_resp_appl_short_name
        , resp_key         => l_responsibility_key
        , security_group   => l_security_group_key
        , description      => NULL
        , start_date       => l_resp_start_date
        , end_date         => l_resp_end_date
    );
    COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        dbms_output.put_line (sqlerrm);
END;
```